# Ubuntu Froze at the loading screen

Tags: boot, networking, mount, network-manager, fsck

I was Trying to enable Ubuntu on Xorg because I have Invidia Driver

but after trying few solutions here my Ubuntu froze on the start screen

i can't enable networking to connect to the wifi

when trying fsck i get this message

> /lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu no such file

> fsck from util-linux 2.37.2

> /dev/sda5 is mounted

> e2fsck cannot continue ubuntu, aborting

so I really don't know what to do or how to solve that

i tried several solutions related to the same issue but nothing

so if someone can help me please